# About the license of Kafka HDFS 2 Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am a little confused about the Confluent Community License and the Confluent connectors.

According to https://www.confluent.io/confluent-community-license-faq/ it applies only to some some Confluent Connectors and in the diagram below it lists Community Connectors under the Apache 2.0 License.

Then, if you search for the [community connectors](https://www.confluent.io/hub/?utm_medium=sem&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=ch.sem_br.nonbrand_tp.prs_tgt.kafka_mt.mbm_rgn.emea_lng.eng_dv.all&utm_term=%2Bkafka%20%2Bconnect&creative=&device=c&placement=&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5Jyy9LC_5wIV2uWaCh1mZwsgEAAYASAAEgJwIfD_BwE)
you can see the Kafka Connect HDFS connector which is Confluent Supported (at the time of writing this question the version is: confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs:5.4.

The page for the connector is this:
https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs

There, however, if you click on the Licensing page you can see the Confluent Community License and not the Apache 2.0 License.

Has the licensing for the HDFS (version 2, sink) connector changed?

Note: I want to use the connector in production and so i would like to have the Apache 2.0 License. The Confluent Community License is prohibitive in this sense.

Thanks for your time and assistance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow isn't suited for questions about software licencing. Try Law.SE.

Comment: Where does it state you cannot use it in production? AFAIK, the only limitation is that you cannot sell or rebrand the services of the HDFS connector under the license

Comment: "Note: I want to use the connector in production… Confluent Community License is prohibitive in this sense." - can you edit your question to explain this assumption please? Are you doing something in production that you think violates CCL?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are confusing [Confluent Community License](https://www.confluent.io/confluent-community-license/) and Confluent Enterprise License. You don't have to pay for Confluent Community License; The license lets you download, modify and re-distribute the code of Confluent's community software. From my point of view, the only restrictions that this type of license adds are competitive use cases. For example:

> For purposes of this Agreement, “Excluded Purpose” means making
>   available any software-as-a-service, platform-as-a-service,
>   infrastructure-as-a-service or other similar online service that
>   competes with Confluent products or services that provide the Software

I believe that the following diagram should shed some more light ([source](https://www.confluent.io/blog/developers-guide-confluent-community-license/)):

[image]

For Kafka Connect in particular, community connectors are licensed under Apache 2.0 License, while Confluent Connectors are licensed under Confluent Community License.

As far as I know, those changes were made by Confluent last year. I assume that the Confluent Hub has the latest information so I believe the Confluent HDFS connector is licensed under Confluent Community License (but most probably -depending on your usecase- this doesn't stop you from using it in production).